Exclude JsQuery from Litespeed Cache
My site using slider image that does'nt show when Litespeed Cache is on. I need to exclude it from the jsquery exclude list, but i dont know what it's name.
My site is: ichii.id
I've already tried to look it by using browser developer tool, but i dont get it.

https://prnt.sc/JxFXtAKcIf_G

https://prnt.sc/q7JTXpiTn5e7

Also if you are using Litespeed Cache then there must be an option of remove cache or regenerate cache or something like that. fix your jQuery code issue and regenerate the cache.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
